# Not all media files discovered by media apps

Tags: media-player, media-scanner, media-files

I have folder on my sd card called podcasts. It contains  subfolders of podcasts. My problem is the media players I have tried only display some of the podcast files as being available to play.

There doesn't seem to be any reason why the displayed files should be playable and the others not. I have tried clearing the data of the "media storage" app as well as running a "rescan sd card" app, to no avail.

So, any ideas as to how I can get all of my podcasts to be playable in a media player?

UPDATE: The problem seemed be caused by Winamp not playing wma format files, even though it's meant to support them. Have converted them to mp3 and they now appear in Winamp and can be played

Comment: Does any of the folders contain a `.nomedia` file? That would be a marker for the media scanner to exclude its contents. If not, you might want to check the system logs once you triggered the media scanner, to look out for any error messages.

Comment: No .nomedia file. The problem seemed be caused by Winamp not playing wma format files, even though it's meant to support them. Have converted them to mp3 and they now appear in Winamp and can be played.

Comment: You may want to put that as an answer (and accept it 2 days later when you can), as it looks like this *is* the answer to your question, right? ;)

Comment: It doesn't explain what was going on but the problem has gone away. Have added it as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed be caused by Winamp not playing wma format files, even though it's meant to support them. Have converted them to mp3 and they now appear in Winamp and can be played.